# SQL Server Stored Procedure with CHAR parm

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

This one DOES NOT work fine:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE rconte.spPesquisaPesIdDadoCodigo24
    (
    @pPesCodigo24 char
    )
    AS
    SELECT pesId FROM tblPesquisas where pesIdentificadorRandomico24ParaEmail = @pPesCodigo24
    RETURN
```

---

This one WORKS FINE:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE rconte.spPesquisaPesIdDadoCodigo24
    (
    @pPesCodigo24 char(24)
    )
    AS
    SELECT pesId FROM tblPesquisas where pesIdentificadorRandomico24ParaEmail = @pPesCodigo24
    RETURN
```

---

Why, please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Becuase by default the length is 1

But it depends on how you use it

Also make sure to read this

http://beyondrelational.com/blogs/madhivanan/archive/2007/12/04/column-length-and-data-length.aspx

Comment: Does that mean that if the parm value is 'abcdef' the comparison will be made as 
where pesIdentificadorRandomico24ParaEmail = 'a'
ignoring the rest of the string, resulting in "no match" at all ?